# sort multiple columns numeric

Tags: sort

i am trying to sort a file that has 600 columns. i want it gives me highest number number in all on top (descending order for each field)
i just slice the file which is space separated to see if it is working fine. i tried out these commands but 
seems as if i am doing something wrong

```
$ cat test.txt
+0.07273 +0.67860
-6.99580 -0.44278 
-7.21295 +0.19793

$ sort -nr test.txt # (just sorted column one)
-7.21295 +0.19793
-6.99580 -0.44278 
+0.07273 +0.67860

$ sort -k1,1nr -k2,2nr test.txt # (just sorted column one)
+0.0727  +0.67860
-6.99580 -0.44278 
-7.21295 +0.19793
```

how can i sort entire columns in descending order. it will be hard to use k 600 times

Comment: to sort 600 columns in descending order?

Comment: yes the file has mix of positive, negatives and zeros. i guess they could have exponents so i even use -g. columns are space separated i even use -t ' '

Comment: You can't sort the columns independently with `sort`.

Comment: The 2nd sort command reverse-numerically sorts on the **first** column as expected. Your first sort command should sort on the first column but doesn't. What implementation of sort is that.

Comment: sorry stephane i am not clear sort (GNU coreutils) 8.25

Comment: @don_crissti so how can i get descending values in all columns

Comment: You have to split the file by columns into separate pieces, sort each piece then paste the results back into a single file.

Comment: i see. is this the only option.

Comment: @Star what's the difficulty? Loop across each column, `cut` it out, `sort` it. Then `paste` the results at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
<test.txt awk '{for (c = 1; c<=NF; c++) print c, $c}' |
  LC_ALL=C sort -k2,2rg |
  awk '{print $1, r[$1]++, $2}' |
  sort -sk2,2n -k1,1n | awk '
    {printf "%s", ($2 == prev ? (NR == 1 ? "" : " ") : "\n") $3; prev = $2}
    END {print ""}'
```

That is:

1. print each cell on one line as `<column-number> <value>`.
2. Sort that by *value* (note the `g` (GNU extension) instead of `n` as `n` doesn't understand the `+`¹) and with `LC_ALL=C` to make sure `.` is recognised as the decimal radix.
3. We have column numbers and values. But in order to rebuild the table, we compute the raw number here incrementing it each time we see the same column number
4. We call sort again to sort by raw and then col (`-s` for *stable* also a GNU extension)
5. And have `awk` process those to print in columns again.

Just before the  last step,  on your input, that gives:

```
1 0 +0.07273
2 0 +0.67860
1 1 -6.99580
2 1 +0.19793
1 2 -7.21295
2 2 -0.44278
```

Which `awk` turns to:

```
+0.07273 +0.67860
-6.99580 +0.19793
-7.21295 -0.44278
```

Where each column is sorted numerically from biggest to smallest.

Now, you might find it easier to use `perl` which:

- supports those `+1.123` numbers out of the box
- only considers `.` as the decimal radix regardless of the locale of the user
- has sorting built-in and structures to hold tables (note that GNU `awk` can do that as well)

That means the whole input has to be loaded in memory though.

```
<test.txt perl -lane '
   my $n; push @{$c[$n++]}, $_ for @F;
   END {
     @{$_} = sort {$b <=> $a} @{$_} for @c; # sort the columns in 
                                            # reverse-numerical order
     for ($r = 0; $r < $.; $r++) {
       print join " ", map {$c[$_]->[$r]} (0..$#c)
     }
   }'
```

---

¹ For `-n`, only numbers formatted as `123`, `1.12` or `-12`, `-12.34` are recognised (with optional leading blanks). To get the value of a key, `sort` gets the part from the start of the string that matches that pattern, in the case of `12e+3`, that's `12`. In the case of `+12.3`, it's the empty string, so `0`. With `-g`, GNU `sort` recognises all those `+12`, `12e+3` numbers.

```
$ printf '%s\n' 1 2 10 2e3 +2 +10 inf +1 | sort -n
+1
+10
+2
inf
1
2
2e3
10
$ printf '%s\n' 1 2 10 2e3 +2 +10 inf +1 | sort -g
1
+1
2
+2
10
+10
2e3
inf
```